# Выборка данных из базы данных MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

Пишу скрипт для вывода данных из БД.

```
<?php

$sql_works = "SELECT * FROM works 
    LEFT JOIN otdel ON works.id = otdel.id_type 
    LEFT JOIN exam ON otdel.id_otdel = exam.id_otd 
    LEFT JOIN child_exam ON exam.id_exam = child_exam.id_exam";

$result = mysql_query($sql_works);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (isset($data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['name_exam']])) { 
        $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['name_exam']]['fields'] = $row; 
    }
    $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['name_exam']]['child'][] = $row['name_ch_exam'];
}


echo "<ul class='clop'>";
foreach ($data as $name_work => $otdel_array) {
    echo "<li class='work_title'>" . $name_work . "</li>" ;
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($otdel_array as $otdel_name => $exam_names) {
        echo "<li class='otdel'>" . $otdel_name . "</li>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($exam_names as $exam_name){ 
            echo "<li class='bg_li'>".$exam_name['fields']['name_exam'] ." " .$exam_name['fields']['performer'] ."</li>
            <ul><li>" . implode('</li><li>', $exam_names['child']) . "</li></ul>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Категорически отказывается выводить 4 уровень вложенности из таблицы *child_exam*. Ошибка при выводе

> implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed.

Comment: и лучше раделять вопрос на части - mysql и php. что возвращает запрс mysql? соответствуют ли данные ожидаемым? или ошибка в их использовании в php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно разобрался, то Вам надо

```
implode('</li><li>', $exam_names['child'])
```

заменить на

```
implode('</li><li>', $exam_name['child'])
```